# Modify JSON data format for use with FLOT chart

Tags: php, json, flot

I am trying to create a JSON object to hold data for use with a [FLOT](http://www.flotcharts.org/) chart.  The documentation says that the Data Format should be an array of points like this:

```
[ [1, 3], [2, 14.01], [3.5, 3.14] ]
```

The problem that I am having is that my AJAX call is returning a JSON object with a Data Format like this:

```
Rate: [96, 74, 73, 96, 124, 104]
Year: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
```

Can someone explain how I should modify this code so that it creates the correct data format that is required for the FLOT chart?  Thanks.

```
function ajaxmuniChart1c(){
$muni = $this->input->POST('muni');
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT SaleYear AS Y, NewSaleType AS T, count(*) AS C, format((sum(SalePrice) / sum(Quantity1)),0) AS R FROM tblsales WHERE  tblsales.SaleYear > 2007 AND tblsales.Quantity1 > 2000 AND (tblsales.NewSaleType = 'Industrial') AND tblsales.Municipality = '".$muni."' GROUP BY T,Y ORDER BY T,Y");
$json_SaleYear = array();
$json_AvrgRate = array();
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
    $json_SaleYear[] = $row['Y'];
    $json_AvrgRate[] = $row['R'];
}
$json['Year'] = $json_SaleYear;
$json['Rate'] = $json_AvrgRate;            
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place them into the same row at the point of placing them into PHP Array during the `foreach` results loop:

```
/** 
 *   Bind the two on the
 *   same row whilst looping
 *   the results
**/
foreach ( $q->result_array() as $row ){
    $JsonArray[] = array( $row['Y'] => $row['R'] );
}

/**
 *   Expected Array Result:
**/
print_r( $JsonArray );

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [2008] => 96
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2009] => 74
    )

/**
 *   echo this out as an JSON String
**/
echo json_encode( $JsonArray );
```

And this'll provide you with:

```
  [{"2008":96},{"2009":74},{"2010":73},{"2011":96},{"2012":124},{"2013":104}]
```

As described in the documentation, you can provide an label to your data. 
To do this, you'd need to push it into an multidimensional array that branches out the:

- Label
- Data

Before encoding it into an JSON Array, we can adjoin the two together:

```
/**
 *  Create a new variable 
 *  two join the two
**/
$WithLabels = array( 
    "label" => "Sales by Years",
    "data" => $JsonArray
);

echo json_encode( $WithLabels );
```

Encoding this, provides us finally with the following:

```
{
  "label" : "Sales by Years",
  "data"  : [{"2009":74},
             {"2010":73},
             {"2011":96},
             {"2012":124},
             {"2013":104}]
}
```

Comment: @DanielAttard Updated my answer to be a little more elaborate =)

Comment: One more quick question for you.  How can I modify your code so that I end up with a label for the data?

Comment: @DanielAttard Modified my answer with a bit of description to how =]

Answer (score 0):

Place them into PHP Array during the foreach results loop

```
// PHP CODE     
$data = array();  // empty array
    foreach ($query as $k=>$row) {
        $data[] = array($k, $row->total_price); // store data in array 
    }
    echo json_encode($data);  // json encode
```

Ajax Response on Success

```
success: function(msg) {
                var d1 = msg;
                console.log(d1);
                $.plot($("#chart_lines_fill_nopoints"), [d1]); //chart_lines_fill_nopoints id name 
            }
// Data Should be in this format 
//array(array(1,300),array(1,1300),array(1,200),array(1,500)); etc

// should be in json result 

[[1, 7.8], [2, 7.8], [3, 20.0], [4, 7.8], [5, 7.8]]
```

That's it